# How to eliminate E Zygote?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error

I have this two errors when i start my app at runtime.
I don't understand what is the problem and how can I remove it.

```
06-17 18:10:59.213 22163-22163/? E/Zygote: v2
06-17 18:10:59.213 22163-22163/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10031
06-17 18:10:59.213 22163-22163/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
06-17 18:10:59.213 22163-22163/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1 ver=11
06-17 18:10:59.213 22163-22163/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0035
06-17 18:10:59.213 22163-22163/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
```

I would like to know what are:

```
06-17 18:10:59.213 22163-22163/? E/Zygote: v2
```

and

```
 06-17 18:10:59.213 22163-22163/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does it crash or you just saw this in logcat?

Comment: just saw in logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand what is the problem

There is no problem, other than sometimes Google engineers and device manufacturer engineers make poor choices with respect to logging.

> how can I remove it

You would need to build your own version of Android that contains a copy of the `zygote` that does not contain those two logging statements. These are not coming from your app's code, and your app has no means of controlling them.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So there is no way to eliminate this messages? I understand from your answer that is not a problem, so why they are after "E/" and colored in red?

Comment: @soissy: "so why they are after "E/" and colored in red?" -- because that is what either a Google engineer or a device manufacturer engineer decided to do. "So there is no way to eliminate this messages?" -- short of creating your own custom version of Android, correct.